# Laravel pagination change from ?page=1 to /page/1

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-pagination

I want to change default Laravel pagination behaviour.

I want to change the query string to a route parameter:

```
https://www.example.com/blog?page=2
```

to this:

```
https://www.example.com/blog/page/2
```

I found this package but it is abandoned `spatie/laravel-paginateroute`

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this route declaration:

```php
Route::get('/blog/page/{page}', 'BlogController@index')->name('blog.index');
```

In your `BlogController`:

```php
public function index($page)
{
    //paginate($perPage = null, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null)
    $blogs = Blog::paginate(15, ['*'], 'page', $page);

    return view('blog.index', compact('blogs));
}
```

Comment: please consider accepting and upvoting this answer if it solve your question